# Receiving 'fe_sendauth: no password supplied' error using AWS Aurora database with Postgres engine, but only when performing unit tests

Tags: python, postgresql, python-unittest, rds, amazon-aurora

I've created a Flask API connecting to an RDS Aurora database using the Postgres engine. The endpoints work fine, and I can connect to them using Postman and cURL. When I try to connect via a unittest script, however, I receive the following error:

fe_sendauth: no password supplied

I'm not sure why it would only occur when tests are being run, does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
export POSTGRES_USER=" your pc username"
export POSTGRES_PW="your pc password"
```

It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue,to solve it i had to edit

```
sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

in METHOD column from MD5 to trust

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

     # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
     local   all             all                                     trust
     # IPv4 local connections:
     host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
     # IPv6 local connections:
     host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```